# Can we mipmap depth textures?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsles

I wanted to know, is it possible to mipmap a depth texture. If, yes then how it will work and were to use it.

Search a lot, but didn't get good explanation anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Depth texture is bound to standard GL_TEXTURE_2D target.

From `glTexImage2d`:

> level : Specifies the level-of-detail number. Level 0 is the base image level. Level n is the nth mipmap reduction image.

However, if you read into [`OES_depth_texture`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_depth_texture.txt) specification, you'll find that:

> WG decided to disallow manual generation of mipmaps for a depth texture.